# How do I identify the remote db agent name to use in create_database_destination on Oracle 11gR2?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, jobs

I am trying to setup DBMS_SCHEDULER in Oracle 11g to run a remote database job.

I have a remote Oracle 11g R2 database on unix and a local one on Windows.

I read that you can install the oracle scheduler agent from the 11g client install for machines that don't have Oracle installed but this is not needed for running remote jobs if Oracle is present on both machines.  With the remote agent installation, you run schagent and provide parameters to register the agent to the remote machine but I cant find any instructions on the web regarding how to register remote agents when both machines have Oracle installed or what to use as the agent name in this case.

I have added an entry to tnsnames.ora for the remote DB and can tnsping, etc.

If I run the `dbms_scheduler.create_database_destination` procedure, it requires an agent name but where can I find this for the database or how can I check that it is running on Unix or Windows?

Comment: Is a database link and a local job a better idea, or isn't that an option?

Comment: my understanding of the functionality provided is that you don't need to install remote agents if you have an Oracle database installed - there are plenty of descriptions about how to register a remote agent to the local one so you can call remote external jobs but nothing about how to register the agent on another Oracle database.  Didn't really want to use the database link route because there could be many Oracle databases I want to run jobs on from a central one so want to know the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduler agent is part of database Oracle Home. Anyway must be manually deployed; there is no way to use the database as agent. I think that the documentation is misleading on this case. To help you I will write steps to be performed for agent configuration. I suppose that on the central database you have already enabled HTTP port (etc.).
On the remote database (the one where agent have to be configure):

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME\bin
extjobo -createagentzip execution_agent.zip
```

Unzip the file into a directory under the $ORACLE_HOME\scheduler.

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME\scheduler
unzip execution_agent.zip
```

Modify the file named schagent.conf located in the $ORACLE_HOME\scheduler\execution_agent directory setting the Scheduler Agent port number to listen for connections. (the one you should have already set with dbms_xdb.sethttpport() )

```
PORT=<schagent_port>
```

You have to run the root.sh to fix the uid. (You can follow the README file in the execution_agent directory and run the root.sh). **NOTE** Verify a directory named /wallet exists under /execution_agent/data before running root.sh. If not create them manually and then run root.sh.

Register the database with.

```
set ORACLE_SID=<your sid>
cd $ORACLE_HOME\scheduler\execution_agent\bin
schagent -registerdatabase <db_host> <db_http_port>
```

You will be asked to input the registration password. Last start manually the agent:

```
schagent -start
```

These steps will install and configure the agent. Now you can create credentials on the central database and create the database destination. Database destination can exists along with a remote agent destination.